# Self Hosted Web API Authentication

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I have a self hosted Web API running, which using DotNetOpenAuth to issue authorization tokens.  Basically, the project consists of 2 ApiController endpoints (Authorize and Token).  I would like to force the client to have to log in to a form, prior to being able to call either endpoint.  (Forms Authentication I guess).  However, doesn't seem like it works for self hosted Web API projects, so, I am trying to implement something myself.

As of now, when the user calls the Authorize web get method, I render the login page and force them to login.  However, I would like to have a mechanism in place so that once the user logs in, I can send a cookie response.  I understand that if you write the cookie in the response, the browser will automatically send any relevant cookies upon subsequent requests.

However, my test client uses a HttpWebRequest to call my web api.  Do I have to build the mechanism to save the response cookie to a file on the hard disk, and then, read it back, and associate with the HttpWebRequest on subsequent requests?  Or ,  is there something built into the framework which I can leverage (just like how a browser would automatically take care of this for me).

I figured that once I could figure this part out, I could just extend the AuthorizationFilterAttribute, and use that to check the validity of the incoming cookie.

Thanks.  Any help or suggestion is appreciated!